# getting error :: 'TestLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

Below is code of my framework for testing which I am building, but I am getting the error `'TestLogin' object has no attribute 'driver'`.

Confest.py code:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = None


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--browser_name", action="store", default="chrome",
    )


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def setup(request):
    """
      hdhdhdh
    """
    browser_name = request.config.getoption("--browser_name")
    if browser_name == "chrome":
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Devesh/PycharmProjects/E-mandi/Drivers/chromedriver.exe')
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:/Users/Devesh/PycharmProjects/E-mandi/Drivers/geckodriver.exe')
        driver.get('http://www.facebook.com/login') (for example not real url)
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        request.cls.driver = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
        request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

BaseClass:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup")
class BaseClass:
    pass
```

LoginPage:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    mobile = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-untouched.ng-pristine.ng-invalid")

    def loginclick(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(*LoginPage.mobile)
```

test_main:

```
from Pageobjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from Utilities.BaseClass import BaseClass


class TestLogin(BaseClass):
    def test_01_login(self):
        loginpage = LoginPage(self.driver)
        loginpage.loginclick().click()
```

Comment: there is no global variable to access as self.driver ,

Comment: can specify where i missed it and in which file cuz i cant debugg this?

Comment: in test_main: whch is the self.driver?

Comment: in test main self.driver is a value(driver is value) which i am passing tom constructor in class Loginpage  to make coneection call method of loginclick() from the Loginpage class.

Comment: wer r u getting that value from ? There is no variable decalred in  testlogin class

Comment: @PDHide thanks its resolve there is some error of indantation in code.